# Mysql guidance wanted :)

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables:

- recipe // this one contains the items what are in the recipe
- item // these are the list of known items. We also store a starting price for the items here.
- receipt // this is the prices of the items

This query will return me with the item name from the recipe and with the latest price.
I have a problem with this query. If there is no record for the item in receipt that item won't show up in my list. How can i do that if there is no record in the receipt then return the item with it's starting price from the `item` table?

```
SELECT i.name, r.price
FROM recipe_items ri
JOIN receipt r ON (ri.item = r.item)
JOIN item i ON (ri.item = i.id)
LEFT OUTER JOIN receipt r1 ON (r.item = r1.item AND 
     (r.date < r1.date OR r.date = r1.date AND r.id < r1.id)) 
WHERE r1.id IS NULL AND ri.recipe_id = 2
GROUP BY ri.item
```

Comment: Make your join onto the `r` table a left join like `r1` is. You've already solved the majority of this problem.

Comment: @scragar Thank you so much it was a frustrating mistake this is the solution. Could please drop some lines as a answer so i can accept it?

Answer (score 0):

Could that be what you want?

```
SELECT i.name, IFNULL(r.price,i.price) as price
FROM recipe_items ri
INNER JOIN item i ON (ri.item = i.id)
LEFT OUTER JOIN receipt r USING item
WHERE ri.recipe_id = 2
GROUP BY ri.item
ORDER BY r.date
```